# null reference exception was unhandled in class with textboxes

Tags: vb.net

So I am doing a project for my class where we have to write a class to make a cash register. Its a simple register with two buttons: Add and Subtract. You type the amount you want into the first textbox and the result show in the second. I have never worked with classes and do not understand most of the lingo that go with it so dummed down answers would be wonderful! This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class frmRegister

    Dim reg As CashRegister
    Structure Equations
        Dim Amount As Double
        Dim Balance As Double
    End Structure
    Class CashRegister
        Private xAmount As Double
        Private xBalance As Double

        Public Property Amount As Double
            Get
                Return xAmount
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                xAmount = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Balance As Double
            Get
                Return xBalance
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                xBalance = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Function calc_sum() As Double
            Dim AddMethod As Double
            AddMethod = xBalance + xAmount
            Return AddMethod
        End Function
        Function calc_sub() As Double
            Dim SubtractMethod As Double
            SubtractMethod = xBalance - xAmount
            Return SubtractMethod
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Sub frmRegister_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If txtBalance.Text = "" Then
            txtBalance.Text = "0"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        reg.Amount = txtAmount.Text
        reg.Balance = txtBalance.Text
        txtBalance.Text = FormatCurrency(reg.calc_sum)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
        reg.Amount = txtAmount.Text
        reg.Balance = txtBalance.Text
        txtBalance.Text = FormatCurrency(reg.calc_sub)
        If txtBalance.Text < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Transaction Cannot Result in Negative Balance!")
            txtBalance.Text = "0"
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

The problem occurs when I get to the buttons and I reference the txtboxes. They underline txtAmount.text and say null reference exception was unhandled. What am I doing wrong. How is it a null? I tried adding cdbl in front but that doesn't make a difference

Comment: I think you must use equations.Amount instead of reg.Amount or may be you are confused between equations.Amount and reg.Amount

Comment: or you may use reg.xAmount instead of reg.Amount

Answer (score 1):

The `reg` variable is `Nothing` so you can not call a method on it. Unlike with structures where the structure exists as soon as you create a variable of that type, with classes you have to explicitly insatiate the class. The best way to correct this would be to add `reg = new CashRegister()` to `frmRegister_Load`.

The reason for this is that whilst a structure is stored directly in the variable the class is a reference to an instance and if is valid for the variable to not point to an instance but it is not valid for a variable to not contain something.

For a structure the memory is stored directly in the stack like this

```
Equations
Amount
Balance
```

so the variable must is exist as the space for it exists.

For a class the variable just contains the location of the class in the heap so you have to create an *instance* using new for the variable to point to.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you! So after the the main class, you have to declare it as new in the next section to get it to work?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your CashRegister class is not the same as the form class that contains the text boxes. If that's so, then you need a reference to the form (another property for your class, which you may set in the constructor). Then you use (the name of that reference).txtBalance.Text or (the name of that reference).txtAmount.Text, as needed.

Comment: This would be flagged at compile time and not generate a NullReferenceException